# How to override kind of segue in code?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

Simply I have one segue of kind **Show** from `FirstViewController` to the `SecondViewController`.
I call it on iPad and iPhone from two places of my `FirstViewController`. It is ok, but in one case I need to present `SecondViewController` as a `.Popover`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {

        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {

            let student = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Student
            secondViewController.schoolClass = schoolClass
            secondViewController.student = student

        } else {

            secondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
            secondViewController.schoolClass = schoolClass

            let popoverPresentationController = studentFormViewController.popoverPresentationController
            popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
            popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Up
            popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = addStudentBarButtonItem
        }
    }
}
```

It doesnt work.

**Any ideas how to override kind of segue from storyboard in code?**

Comment: Have you thought about having a second segue with the .Popover properties. This means that you would not need so much code in your prepareForSegue.

Answer (score -1):

You should use custom segues:

1. implement custom segue by subclassing UIStoryboardSegue class and override prepare() method. (In prepare() method you implement all required behaviour (controllers animation, presentation and so on depending on your case);
2. Change you segue type from push to custom in the interface builder, and pick your implementation in class property (like on image below)

[image: Using custom segue]

Best regards!